# permission denied for schema ctgov; SQL state: 42501

Tags: postgresql

I am new to postgresql and I would grateful if you could please advise on how-to resolve the following error..

I have issued the followed commands:

```
SELECT sub1.nct_id, sub1.condition, sub1.condition_name,
        sub2.overall_status, sub2.participants,
        e.criteria,
        f.city, f.state, f.country,
        i.intervention_type, i.name AS intervention
FROM (SELECT c.nct_id, c.name AS condition, c.downcase_name AS condition_name
        FROM ctgov.conditions AS c
-- selecting only cancer trials before joining
        WHERE c.name ILIKE '%cancer%') sub1                                 
JOIN (SELECT s.nct_id, s.overall_status, s.enrollment AS participants
        FROM ctgov.studies AS s
-- selecting only completed cancer trials before joining    
        WHERE s.overall_status = 'Completed') sub2                          
    ON sub1.nct_id = sub2.nct_id
JOIN ctgov.eligibilities AS e
    ON sub1.nct_id = e.nct_id
JOIN ctgov.facilities AS f
    ON sub1.nct_id = f.nct_id
JOIN ctgov.interventions AS i
    ON sub1.nct_id = i.nct_id;
```

And the error is:
ERROR:  permission denied for schema ctgov
SQL state: 42501

Could you please advise on how to setup the privileges to have access to the tables defined in schema?

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your user lacks the permission to access objects in schema `ctgov`. The owner of that schema (or a superuser) can remedy that with

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA ctgov TO your_user_name;
```

Your user will also need to have the `SELECT` privilege on the tables and views that you want to use.